# Xamarin Forms/ReactiveUI Router - Show child View and execute parent ViewModel code after child View is closed

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, reactive-programming, reactiveui

In my parent ViewModel, I'm using the following code to navigate to a `ChildView` using ReactiveUI's routing

```
appBootstrapper.Router.Navigate.Execute(new ChildViewModel(HostScreen)).Subscribe();
```

This code works as expected.

However, when the child view is closed, I want to perform some extra operations (let's use the example of hiding an activity indicator via a bool ViewModel property), eg

```
ShowActivityIndicator = true;
appBootstrapper.Router.Navigate.Execute(new ChildViewModel(HostScreen)).Subscribe();
ShowActivityIndicator = false;
```

This code does not perform as expected because the child View is shown, and then `ShowActivityIndicator = false;` is executed immediately.

How do I rewrite the code so that `ShowActivityIndicator = false;` is executed ***after*** the `ChildView` is closed? Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Glenn's suggestion, I have tried to use the `WhenNavigatingFromObservable().Subscribe(...)` technique, but the lambda code never executes. My code is as follows...

```
var microsoftSignInVM = new ViewModel.MicrosoftSignInVM(HostScreen);
//
microsoftSignInVM.WhenNavigatingFromObservable().Subscribe((_) =>
{
    ShowActivityIndicator = true;
    //
    Data.Synchronisation.SynchroniseLocalDataCacheAsync();
    //
    appBootstrapper.Router.Navigate.Execute(new ViewModel.SelectJobVM(HostScreen)).Subscribe();
    //
    ShowActivityIndicator = false;
});
//
appBootstrapper.Router.Navigate.Execute(microsoftSignInVM).Subscribe();
```

I placed a breakpoint within the lambda and it never gets hit.

---

**UPDATE 2 - UPDATED**

I've created a couple of minimal test classes. **THESE WORK FINE IN A WPF PROJECT, BUT DO NOT WORK USING XAMARIN FORMS** ...

**Shared**

**TestAV.xaml.cs**

```
namespace TestApp.Test
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TestAV : ReactiveContentPage<TestAVM>
    {
        public TestAV()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
                //
                this.WhenActivated(
                    disposables =>
                    {
                        this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.ClickCommand, x => x.button)
                            .DisposeWith(disposables);
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

**TestAVM.cs**

```
namespace TestApp.Test
{
    public class TestAVM : ReactiveObject, IEnableLogger, IRoutableViewModel
    {
        public TestAVM(IScreen hostScreen)
        {
            _HostScreen = hostScreen;
            //
            TestBVM testBVM = new TestBVM(_HostScreen);
            //
            _ClickCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() => _HostScreen.Router.Navigate.Execute(testBVM).Select(_ => Unit.Default));
            //
            testBVM.WhenNavigatingFromObservable().Subscribe((_) =>
            {
                ShowActivityIndicator = true;
            });
        }
        //
        public bool ShowActivityIndicator { get; set; }
        //
        private readonly ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> _ClickCommand; public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> ClickCommand => _ClickCommand;
        //
        private readonly IScreen _HostScreen; public IScreen HostScreen => _HostScreen;
        //
        public string UrlPathSegment => "TestA";
    }
}
```

**TestBV.xaml.cs**

```
namespace TestApp.Test
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TestBV : ReactiveContentPage<TestBVM>
    {
        public TestBV()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            this.WhenActivated(
                disposables =>
                {
                    this
                        .BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.ClickCommand, x => x.button)
                        .DisposeWith(disposables);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

**TestBVM.cs**

```
namespace TestApp.Test
{
    public class TestBVM : ReactiveObject, IEnableLogger, IRoutableViewModel
    {
        public TestBVM(IScreen hostScreen)
        {
            _HostScreen = hostScreen;
        }
        //
        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> ClickCommand => _HostScreen.Router.NavigateBack;
        //
        private readonly IScreen _HostScreen; public IScreen HostScreen => _HostScreen;
        //
        public string UrlPathSegment => "TestB";
    }
}
```

**Xamarin Specific Files**

**AppBootstrapper.cs**

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public class AppBootstrapper : ReactiveObject, IScreen
    {
        public AppBootstrapper(IMutableDependencyResolver dependencyResolver = null, RoutingState router = null)
        {
            Router = router ?? new RoutingState();
            //
            RegisterParts(dependencyResolver ?? Locator.CurrentMutable);
            //
            Router.Navigate.Execute(new Test.TestAVM(this));
        }

        public RoutingState Router { get; private set; }

        private void RegisterParts(IMutableDependencyResolver dependencyResolver)
        {
            dependencyResolver.RegisterConstant(this, typeof(IScreen));
            //
            dependencyResolver.Register(() => new Test.TestAV(), typeof(IViewFor<Test.TestAVM>));
            dependencyResolver.Register(() => new Test.TestBV(), typeof(IViewFor<Test.TestBVM>));
        }

        public Page CreateMainPage()
        {
            return new RoutedViewHost();
        }
    }
}
```

**TestAV.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rxui:ReactiveContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                           xmlns:rxui="clr-namespace:ReactiveUI.XamForms;assembly=ReactiveUI.XamForms"
                          xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestApp.Test"
                          x:TypeArguments="vm:TestAVM"
                        x:Class="TestApp.Test.TestAV">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button x:Name="button" Text="click A" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</rxui:ReactiveContentPage>
```

**TestBV.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rxui:ReactiveContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                           xmlns:rxui="clr-namespace:ReactiveUI.XamForms;assembly=ReactiveUI.XamForms"
                          xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestApp.Test"
                          x:TypeArguments="vm:TestBVM"
             x:Class="TestApp.Test.TestBV">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button x:Name="button" Text="click B" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</rxui:ReactiveContentPage>
```

**WPF Specific Files**

**TestAV.xaml**

```
<rxui:ReactiveUserControl x:Class="TestApp.TestAV"
            x:TypeArguments="vm:TestAVM"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestApp.Test">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="click A" />
    </Grid>
</rxui:ReactiveUserControl>
```

**TestBV.xaml**

```
<rxui:ReactiveUserControl x:Class="TestApp.TestBV"
            x:TypeArguments="vm:TestBVM"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestApp.Test">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="click B" />
    </Grid>
</rxui:ReactiveUserControl>
```

---

It's worth noting that if I use

```
_ClickCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() => _HostScreen.Router.Navigate.Execute(new TestAVM()).Select(_ => Unit.Default));
```

in **TestBVM.cs**, then the lambda fires as expected.

It seems like there is a problem with the Xamarin Forms implementation of `Router.NavigateBack`, but I am open to other observations!

Answer (score 2):

Couple of different ways you could approach it.

The Router has several observables you can subscribe to when operations on the navigation stack are invoked. There is also a extension method in `RoutableViewModelMixin` called `WhenNavigatingFromObservable` you could use.

```cs
public void ShowChildView()
{
    ShowActivityIndicator = true;
    var childViewModel = new ChildViewModel(HostScreen);
    // Use the extension method to get an observable when the child view is navigated away from, subscribe and set the variable.
    childViewModel.WhenNavigatingFromObservable().Subscribe(x => ShowActivityIndicator = false);
    appBootstrapper.Router.Navigate.Execute(childViewModel).Subscribe();
}
```

Second option, if you don't mind the functionality happening on the child, you could use the WhenActivated() mechanic

```cs
public ChildView()
{
    this.WhenActivated(disposable => 
     {
        // do activation logic.
        return new[] { Disposable.Create(() => DoDeactivationLogic());
     }
```

Further details here https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-activated/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried to implement option 1, but for some reason the lamdba in the `childViewModel.WhenNavigatingFromObservable().Subscribe(...)` method never executes?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the actual code I'm using.

Comment: It relies on the HostScreen property being set. So you can pass it in or use DI to store it. The HostScreen contains the router

Comment: Thanks again. I've added a minimal but full example to my question, but the lambda still isn't getting fired... Really can't see what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: I've updated my answer again ... it seems like the problem is something to do with Xamarin Forms' implementation of `Router.NavigateBack`

Comment: Might be worth lodging a issue on the GitHub page. Probably some sort of regression.

Comment: I lodged a issue here you can track https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/2040

Comment: Sorry Glenn. I was getting round to it, I promise ... had to get a load of work done as I'd spent 2 days experimenting and trying to find out what the problem was ... boss was not happy!

Comment: No problem, I'll get some unit tests done in the next day or so and see if I can get a new bug fix out for you this week.